# Richfaces datascroller control width

Tags: css, richfaces

I have the following code:

```
<rich:dataScroller id="scrollerTest" for="userAdminTable"
    fastControls="auto" renderIfSinglePage="false" render="userAdminTable" />
```

The data scroller works fine, but it looks weird, because the width of the table is much larger than the datascroller. It seems like there should be an easy way to control the width of the datascroller, but I am not able to find that info anywhere in the documentation. Do I need to just write custom CSS for this or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Move `rich:dataScroller` inside `rich:dataTable`:

```
<rich:dataTable ...>
    ...
    <f:facet name="footer">
        <rich:dataScroller renderIfSinglePage="false" fastControls="auto" />
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: Well that centered it but it is still not the correct size.

Comment: You can add `style="width: 100%"` in `rich:dataScroller` like `<rich:dataScroller renderIfSinglePage="false" fastControls="auto" style="width: 100%" />`